# Return an eager loaded object in Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I need the eager loaded object instead of the parent object returned to AJAX.

I have 2 tables, Chef and Location.  I want to return all Chefs owning Locations with a particular value in the Locations' city fields.

I can successfully select and filter Locations with linked Chefs eager loaded.  But I want to return the Chefs, not the Locations.  Ideally, the Chefs with their Locations eager loaded would be great.  But how do I select Chefs based on a relationship's field value?

```php
class Location extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'locations';

    public function chef() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Chef');
    }
}

class Chef extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'chefs';

    public function location() {
        return $this->hasMany('Location');
    }
}
```

and in my Controller class I have:

```php
class DishController extends BaseController {
    if ($loc_search) {
        $locations = Location::with('chef')->where('city', 'LIKE', "%$loc_search%");
        $chefstemp = array();
        foreach ($locations->get() as $loc) {
            if (strpos($loc->city, $loc_search) !== FALSE) {
                array_push($chefstemp, $loc->chef);
            }
    }
    return $chefstemp;
    }
}
```

Of course Controller does not return JSON so this doesn't work but I wanted to show my thinking.

Comment: you can try by Defining Fillable Attributes On A Model [link](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment). And to return Json [Read here](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17302901/1661358

Comment: No that didn't help.  I basically want to do:
    Locations::where('city', '=', 'Chicago')->chef();

Comment: With that, you'd do `Locations::where('city', '=' 'Chicago')->fetchAll('chef')`

Comment: `Location::where('city', '=', 'city_name')->fetchAll('chef');` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I meant, if you used the code on the thread I said could be useful. Anywyay, no matter how you do it, Laravel will still make multiple SQL queries, instead of making a JOIN, unless you explicitly tells it to do it.

Comment: I had a similar problem, however mine was a single object I needed which was solved as follows `$locations = Location::with('chef')->where('city', 'LIKE', "%$loc_search%")->first();` whereas your seems to be multiple objects which might be achieved as follows `$locations = Location::with('chef')->where('city', 'LIKE', "%$loc_search%")->get();`. So in the initialization and not your foreach (which would become $locations as $loc). I didn't look in depth into your code but the only issue I foresee is this may return an array instead of an object (not sure on this point) and cause other problems.

Comment: There is no Location::with('chef').  'locations' is simply a table of addresses which can be targeted by any record of 3 relevant tables - 'chefs', 'drivers' and 'customers'.  Multiple Chefs/Drivers/Customers could reuse the same location.  Conversely, a User could have a Chef account and a Customer account with separate locations for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working but I'm making multiple hits to the DB.  MySQL is capable of composing a single Select statement for a found set according to my criteria.  I would still love to find a way to do that in Eloquent.

```
    $chef_ids = array();

    $chefQuery = Chef::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$chef_search%");
    if ($chef_search) {
        foreach ($chefQuery->get(array('id')) as $chef) {
            $chef_ids[] = $chef->id;
        }
    }
    if ($loc_search) {
        $locations = Location::where('city', 'LIKE', "%$loc_search%")->get(array('chef_id'));
        foreach ($locations as $loc) {
            $chef_ids[] = $loc->chef_id;
        }
    }
    $dishes = Dish::whereIn('chef_id', $chef_ids)->with(array('chef', 'dishimage', 'chef.location'))->get();
    return $dishes;
```